# How to disable Autocomplete using web.config in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, web-config

How do I disable autocomplete in all my webpages without writing any code into page.

I need to know if there is any way of setting autocomlete to off in web.config.

Comment: I am specifically asking - how to achieve this using web.config.

Comment: @Ariston, Seem you don't understand my question. so only you are marking this one as duplicate.

Comment: Its not possible to make it on web.config.

Comment: Other possible way is to make custom form control and there to rewrite the form https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter(v=vs.110).aspx  Still need some code, only web.config can not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the below code in your master page (if you have one):

```
$(document).ready(function () { $("input").attr("autocomplete", "off"); });
```

If you don't have one, put on every page.

There is no way to do that in web.config.

Comment: This answer is not what my question is looking for. I am specifically asking use only web.config. - No other place i should write code.

Comment: @VishalPatel this can't be done by the web.config, Arthur Castro his code is the easiest to use just use a master page and include that line just once to turn off the auto complete in every page (that's using th emaster page of course)

Comment: @VishalPatel I answered your question. 

**Question:** "I need to know if there is any way of setting autocomlete to off in web.config."

**Answer:** "There is no way to do that in web.config."

_And gave another way to achieve that._